# Generate id in application or use database generated one?

Tags: design, mysql, dao

I am writing a small app that manages a couple of recipes. I have a MySQL database that is used by my data persistance layer. I need some kind of id in my business objects representing the recipes to use my persistence layer.

Currently i am just calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` on my database after i inserted a new recipe and then assign that id. In a project at my part time job we use a different approach. We generate the ids in our application before inserting and then use them from there.

I think my current approach is better, because i only generate an int (the other application uses an id-generator that factors in time etc) which should be faster for lookups and i can scale the system for multiple applications (because i can put the insert and last_insert_id calls into the same transaction) and i can easily roll back, if something goes wrong while executing the transaction.

Is my reasoning right? Or is there something im missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently I am just calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` on my database

This may give unwanted effects when your application is used by several users at the same time. (Another user could have inserted a new record in the table between the intended insert and the request for the id.) Unless you perform this request within the same database transaction.

Most persistance layers will return the generated ID to use in your application. You should look up how this works in your chosen environment.

Generating an ID in your application can have a similar effect if the last ID given out is requested from the database, incremented in software and then used to insert a new database record. However, if the ID generated in the application is guaranteed to be unique (more or less) by some mechanism, this is an acceptable approach.

Assuming both approaches are safe for multi-user environments, both approaches can be acceptable. The points you name as advantages of your approach can also be applied to the approach of generating an ID. Both approaches can scale and both approaches can be rolled back in the database.

An advantage the latter approach might have over the first, is that it is less dependent on the specific database engine. Thus if a different database engine is chosen at a later point, it may be easier to migrate the software to it (for instance because of differing syntax to request the last inserted ID).

Comment: OXID eShop has an interesting approach. The ID aka OXID is an md5 hash. The negative side-effect is that constraints cannot be used afaik.

Comment: I am doing both actions in the same transaction. The point you make about different database backends is really good, i never thought about other databases not producing id's. I will implement a service class that generates unique ids to handle that for me then. Do you know by any chance, if bigger ORM's use a similar approach? (Asking because you said, that persistance layers usually return an id. i built the very simplistic DAO im using myself, so i have no real environment im working with).

Comment: Most database engines have a built-in function or mechanism that will return the ID generated by a particular insert statement (of course this is different for each database engine). The bigger ORMs will use these functions or mechanisms as part of inserting the record.